# NUnit: assert that a collection contains an element that matches some arbitrary condition

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Not the best title, so let me give an example

I have a method that converts a list of objects into another type.  Say I have the following classes

```
class Person {
  string Name {get;set;}
  int Age {get;set;}
  string Uuid {get;set;}
}

class OtherPerson {
  string FirstName {get;set;}
  string LastName {get;set;}
  DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
  Guid Guid {get;set;}
}
```

My method converts a `List<OtherPerson>` into a `List<Person>`.  I want to write an assertion that, for each element in the input, the output contains an element matching a generic equivalency test.  For instance

```
[Test]
public void MyTest(){
  var person1 = GenerateOtherPerson();

  List<Person> result = _classUnderTest.ConverToPerson(new[]{person1}.ToList());

  //This is what I'm looking for
  Assert.That(result, Contains.Item.Matching(p => AreEquivalent(p, person1)));
}

public bool AreEquivalent(Person p1, OtherPerson p2) {
  return p1.Name == $"{p2.FirstName} {p2.LastName}"
    && p1.Age == DateTime.Now.Year - p2.DateOfBirth.Year
    && p1.Uuid == p2.Guid.ToString();
}
```

Note that this is a simplistic example of looking for only 1 element, but you can easily imagine an extension to this in which I have several `OtherPerson`s and I want to assert that the result of the method contains exactly 1 element matching each of the inputs.

I'm having trouble finding an idiomatic assertion for this.  The best I can come up with is

```
matches = result.Select(p => AreEquivalent(p, person1));
Assert.That(matches, Contains.Item(true));
```

But I'm not a fan of that.  I generally like writing assertions that operate directly on the result of my method, rather than writing code that converts the result into some other form and asserting on that.

Is what I'm looking for possible?

Comment: You can provide a custom comparer with the `Using(comparer)` syntax to most nunit constraints, something like `Does.Contain(person1).Using(...)`

Comment: I tried that, but it looks like the comparers can only compare 2 items of the same type.

Comment: Indeed. another option would be to use the Property constraint `Has.Property("Name").EqualTo($"{person1.FirstName} {person1.LastName}").And.Property("X").EqualTo("Y")` but this is unfortunately very verbose.

Comment: That would work for testing one specific element against another, but still doesn't solve the problem of testing that the collection as a whole contains at least 1 element that matches that condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
Assert.That(result, Has.Some.Matches(new Predicate<Person>(p => { return AreEquivalent(p, person1); }));
```

or if you prefer use `Has.Exactly(1).Matches(...`, which will go through the entire list making sure there are no others that match.

This is actually intended to work (and did work when I first wrote it) but does no longer, probably due to overloads that have been added...

```
Assert.That(result, Has.Some.Matches(p => AreEquivalent(p, person1)));
```

I couldn't make it compile without the `new`, `return` and braces. :-( Maybe you can find a better syntax that works.

BTW, this is the PredicateConstraint, which you can find in the NUnit source code but unfortunately not in the docs. There's even one test of it in NUnit's own tests.

Comment: Either `Assert.That(result, Has.Some.Matches<Person>(p => AreEquivalent(p, person1)));` or `Assert.That(result, Has.Some.Matches((Person p) => AreEquivalent(p, person1)));` should work; you just need to be more explicit about the type.

Answer (score -1):

I will use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`

```
/// <summary>
/// Asserts that expected and actual are exactly equal.  The collections must have the same count,
/// and contain the exact same objects in the same order.
/// If comparer is not null then it will be used to compare the objects.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expected">The first IEnumerable of objects to be considered</param>
/// <param name="actual">The second IEnumerable of objects to be considered</param>
/// <param name="comparer">The IComparer to use in comparing objects from each IEnumerable</param>
public static void AreEqual (IEnumerable expected, IEnumerable actual, IComparer comparer)
{...}
```